# Stop 2 floating DIVS from collapsing while inside another

Tags: html, css

This might be really simple but I just cant wrap my head around it.

CSS

```
#nav_bar{
    max-width:1000px;
    height:41px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}

#left{
    float:left;
    min-width:200px;
    height:41px;
    background-color:red;
}

#right{
    float:right;
    min-width:500px;
    height:41px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="nav_bar">

     <div id="left">
     </div>

     <div id="right">
     </div> 

</div>
```

I'll explain this in colors. Basically I want the red box to float left and the right box to float right inside the yellow box. HOWEVER when I make the browser window smaller everything collapses and the black box goes UNDER the red (outside the yellow). I know this sounds very basic but I don't want it too collapse, I would be happy if it could just stay intact without moving at all and the browser just scrolls horizontally like it normally would if the window becomes too small for the content.

Thanks :)

Comment: You have to set a min-width to #nav_bar

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `#nav_bar` a minimum width large enough to accomodate the two child elements:

```
#nav_bar{
    ...
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9cnLs3f2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add width:1000px or how much you need it to be, on the container. In this case "nav_bar".

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/affp7hbs)

```
#nav_bar{
   max-width:1000px;
   width:1000px;
   height:41px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```